# Entering a function across multiple lines in R

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

this is quite a basic one. I'm trying to write some very long user-defined functions in R, however I dont know how to spread the code across multiple lines so its easy to read.

For example, if i were writing a function for the mean I want it to look like this:

```
meen <- function(x) {
return(mean(x))
}
```

However, whenever I press enter in R it submits the function.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in order to get onto a new line after the first {, and then submit the function i get the following error

```
Error: unexpected input in "meen <- function(x){‚"
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: *whenever I press enter in R it submits the function*...what console/IDE are you using?

Comment: Use a text editor.